# Rx_Swift for Local and Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

How can I implement observable for Local notification and Push notifications when they are received.
In app delegate, We are notify on

```
didReceiveLocalNotification
```

and

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

How can I listen these notification on other screen? I've used NotificationCenter for notify but now I want to use RX-Swift. I've tried with this way but not working.

```
  extension UILocalNotification {
   var notificationSignal : Observable<UILocalNotification> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            observer.on(.Next(self))
            observer.on(.Completed)
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Updated:

Hi, I found a solution for that using same way as you are used but some changes.

```
class NotificationClass {
    static let bus = PublishSubject<AnyObject>()

    static func send(object : AnyObject) {
        bus.onNext(object)
    }

    static func toObservable() -> Observable<AnyObject> {
        return bus
    }

}
```

Send notification from AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    NotificationClass.send(notification)
}
```

Then observe on any other class.

```
    NotificationClass.bus.asObserver()
        .subscribeNext { notification in
            if let notification : UILocalNotification = (notification as! UILocalNotification) {
                print(notification.alertBody)
            }
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Best thing of this class is we can emit and consume anyObject through it.

Comment: You should move your update answer from the question to be a full-fledged answer, then accept your moved full-fledged answer as answering OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
// this would really be UILocalNotification
struct Notif {
    let message: String
}

class MyAppDelegate {
    let localNotification = PublishSubject<Notif>()

    // this would really be `application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)`
    func didReceiveLocalNotification(notif: Notif) {
        localNotification.on(.Next(notif))
    }
}

let appDelegate = MyAppDelegate() // this singleton would normally come from `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`

class SomeClassA {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        appDelegate.localNotification
            .subscribe { notif in
                print(notif)
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}

let a = SomeClassA()

appDelegate.didReceiveLocalNotification(Notif(message: "notif 1"))

let b = SomeClassA()

appDelegate.didReceiveLocalNotification(Notif(message: "notif 2"))
```

I'm still learning RxSwift, so this might not be the best way to do it.  However, it works.